# Sorting collection

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I would like to know how using Linq, I could sort the List if every member in List has EntityData property, which is a class:

```
List<Line> profilesLines = new List<Line>();
Line line = new Line(...);
line.EntityData = new StructuralPart { Guid = "123456", OtherPropertA = 2, Other PropertyB = 3};
```

I know how to sort a List if the properties after which sorting should be done are not inside a class:

```
List<Line> SortedList = profilesLines.OrderBy(ent => ent.EntityData).ToList();
```

But is it possible to make a statement in one line that would cast EnitityData to "StructuralPart" and then sort in based on properties defined in that class?

Comment: Have you tried casting to StructuralPart within your lambda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can cast your `EntityData` attribute to `StructuralPart`.

```
List<Line> sortedList = profilesLines.OrderBy(ent => ((StructuralPart)ent.EntityData).Guid).ToList();
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean something like this:

```
List<Line> SortedList = profilesLines.OrderBy(ent => ent.EntityData.Guid).ThenBy(ent => ent.EntityData.OtherPropertA).ToList();
```

You sort by `Guid` and then by `OtherPropertA`